# controlling exception thrown by external library

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

im trying to scrape some website , i use a service to bypass captcha using their library

here simplified version of my code

```
const dbc = require('./deathbycaptcha.js');
open_tab();

async function open_tab() 
{
    try {

        const captcha = await solvecaptcha('xxxx' ,'somedomain'  ) .catch(function (error) {throw new Error('caperror'); });
        console.log('captcha is solved !');
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log('--------ERRRO--------------------------');
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}


function solvecaptcha(datakey , url )
{
    return new Promise(function(resoulve,  reject){
        const client = new dbc.HttpClient(config.captcha.username, config.captcha.password);
        try
        {
            client.decode({extra: {type: 4, token_params: some_params}}, (captcha) => {

                if (captcha) {
                    resoulve(captcha['text']);
                else
                    reject('cant solve captcha!');          
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            reject('cant solve captcha!');
        }
    });
}
```

so it starts in the `open_Tab` function , i call `solvecaptcha` there and it returnes the solved captcha and its all good ... but sometimes there is a connection error in `deathbycaptcha.js` which will break the whole code

like if i close my internet connection and try this i get this error and the program crashes

```
C:\wamp64\www\domain_check\robot\DBC\deathbycaptcha.js:208
        throw new Error(err.message);
        ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.dbcapi.me api.dbcapi.me:80
    at ClientRequest.form.submit (C:\wamp64\www\domain_check\robot\DBC\deathbycaptcha.js:208:15)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

i like to be able to control this exception so it wouldn't break the whole code , but no matter how many try/catch i use to control this ... ti wouldn't work and still breaks my code

and its this line that cuzes the problem

```
    client.decode({extra: {type: 4, token_params: some_params}}, (captcha) => {

        if (captcha) {
            resoulve(captcha['text']);
        else
            reject('cant solve captcha!');          
    });
```

even though i've wrapped it inside try/catch its no use !

Comment: What is the source code of `deatchbycaptcha.js`? It's not [this one](https://github.com/neyric/node-deatchbycaptcha/blob/master/index.js) at least because there is no line `throw new Error(err.message)` in it.

Comment: @CherryDT i got the lib from their support , here it is https://jsfiddle.net/duq15r37/

Comment: I'd put a try/catch around the `form.submit` callback in their file, and call `cb(null)` manually in the error case. (Or `cb(err)` but then you'd need to check if the result is an error or not.) - since you have the file in your source code anyway (and not as npm package) that is the easiest way. The only other way (other than an uncaught exception handler which would lack all the required context) would be monkey-patching the `form-data` package which is probably the worst way (although it'd work as well). This is just pretty old code...

Comment: @CherryDT thanx , i looked in the lib and saw when it fails to solve a captcha it returns null ... so instead of throwing error in `form.submit` i just return null